# Best way to install deja-dup 37 from Bionic 18.04 repo on Artful 17.10

Tags: apt, package-management, backup, ppa, deja-dup

I'd like to install [deja-dup 37](https://launchpad.net/deja-dup/+announcement/14855) for backups to use the new Google Drive backend. deja-dup 37 is in the [Bionic package repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/utils/deja-dup) but has not been backported to Artful yet.

What would be the best way to install this newer package on Artful? I could add the Bionic package repo and pin some apt priorities, but it looks like the deja-dup 37 package would also pull in a new version of libc6 and some other dependencies. I'm hesitant to change many of the standard libraries on my system.

Building from source also seems to require some newer dependencies.

There seems to be a deja-dup team repo: ppa:deja-dup-team/ppa, but I don't have access to it.

There's a flatpak target in the deja-dup Makefile, but I assume I'd have to build the project in a Bionic VM that has the required dependencies then copy the resulting flatpak to my Artful system. I don't have any experience with flatpaks, would this work?

Finally, I suppose I could check out the version 36 git branch and try to cherry-pick the Google Drive commits.

What would be the best approach?